# Euclidean distance of two matrices

Tags: r

I am writing codes to have the Euclidean distance of two matrices and then storing them in a matrix. Could anyone please review this?

```
a <-matrix(1:2,ncol = 2,nrow = 2)
a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2

b <-matrix(3:6,ncol = 2,nrow = 2)
b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6

n <-matrix(data = NA)
 for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
   for (j in 1:nrow(b)) {
    n[i]<-sum(abs(a[i,]-b[j,])^2)
  }
}
n
```

Comment: something in your code doesn't look correct, maybe you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106567/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-two-matrices-in-r

Comment: Also, you're missing the square root. If you install the `proxy` package, you can do `proxy::dist(a, b, method = "Euclidean")`.

Answer (score 3):

First let's take a quick look at what your code is doing. Your innermost line of code is:

```
n[i]<-sum(abs(a[i,]-b[j,])^2)
```

Due to how you've structured your for loops, this is run for times

1. with i=1 and j=1, setting `n[1]` to the squared distance between row 1 with `a` and row 1 of `b`,
2. with i=1 and j=2, **overwriting** `n[1]` to the squared distance between row 1 of `a` and row 2 of `b`,
3. with i=2 and j=1, setting `n[2]` to the squared distance between row 2 of `a` and row 1 of `b`, and
4. with i=2 and j=2, **overwriting** `n[2]` to the squared distance between row 2 of `a` and row 2 of `b`.

So we end up with `n = c(34, 20)`, the squared distances between each row of `a` and the last row of `b`.

It seems most likely to me that you are trying to compute the distances between each pair of points (since your `n` is structured as a vector). In this case, check out what we accomplish with the following, much simpler code:

```
(a-b)^2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4   16
# [2,]    4   16
```

The resulting matrix is the squared difference of each element in the two matrices. All we need to do is to sum up the rows:

```
n <- rowSums((a-b)^2)
n
# [1] 20 20
```

Or if we wanted the actual distance instead of the squared distance:

```
n <- sqrt(rowSums((a-b)^2))
n
# [1] 4.472136 4.472136
```

Note that we dramatically simplified the calculation; a nice side benefit is that this code is much faster than using a `for` loop in R.